# Google OAuth API to get user's email address?

Tags: email, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

I am playing with Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground using my own personal Google account, but I cannot seem to recover my Gmail address using the playground.

The scope I am using is:

```
email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

But when I call the API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo
```

I get various information about the user such as family name, first name, gender, picture, etc. but it does not return the user's email.

How do I retrieve the user's email address? Do I have the wrong scope or am I calling the wrong API? I feel like this should be very simple but I have literally been trying to figure this out for hours and I cannot find an API and scope combination that consistently provides the user's email address.

Comment: I just used the playground with those scopes and that API method and my email address was in the response. You might also try `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me` to get the email address.

Comment: The problem is that it works inconsistently. On some users it seems to include the email address, and on others it doesn't.

Comment: Are you always calling the API method authenticated as `me`? Or are you authenticating as one user and getting profile details for other people?

Comment: That's a great question. Yes, I am only trying to get the email address of the user that authenticated.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Update: December 2018**

On December 20th, Google announced that the Google+ API would be turned down in March 2019, with intermittent failure starting at the end of January 2019. As part of the **the `plus.people.get` endpoint is deprecated and scheduled to be terminated**.

The `userinfo` endpoint is de-deprecated (see clarification) and should provide the info assuming

1. You request the `https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project` scope and
2. You request the `email` field.

**Clarification: 24 Jan 2019**

Google [documented](http://web.archive.org/web/20181011135827/https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration#changes) that the userinfo (v2) endpoint was deprecated, but later changed it to "deprecated, but kept available for backwards compatibility".

[Current documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation) discusses getting profile and email information through the currently supported `openid` method. This includes using the "userinfo" endpoint specified in their [discovery document](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#discovery), as required by OpenID Connect.

At the moment, that URL is `https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo`, but this has changed in the past and the discovery document at `https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` is the authoritative source for the URL to use.

So, to be clear:

- The old userinfo URL is maintained for backwards compatibility
- The new userinfo URL is available at the discovery document

Regardless, the plus version of anything (described below) is [deprecated and scheduled to be removed](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown).

**Original Answer**

There are a lot of issues here in what you're doing and how you're trying to do it.

For starters, the `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` endpoint is deprecated, and scheduled to be removed in September 2014. It has begun working inconsistently - so don't use it.

As @abraham noted, you'll use the [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) endpoint at `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me`. This should give you the [emails](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people#emails) field containing an array of addresses. In your case, there will likely be only one that has a type of "account".

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the deprecation but didn't realize that it was coming so soon, I'll change my implementation to use this endpoint. So far it seems to be consistently providing the email address.

Comment: got it working by adding "email" scope in the google button <div> itself. Earlier i was adding the scope through php like, $client->setScopes(SCOPES_ARRAY); but won't worked, now after adding scope in google buttons data-scope attribute did the work....

Comment: @Prisoner I am starting new with google oauth2. Just like fb recently made it optional for the user to provide their email during signup, do google have the same feature? Or will we be definitely getting the email of the user who signed up?

Comment: I wonder if the OAuth2 userinfo API is really deprecated, because it's still there in the [scopes documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes), API explorer and in OAuth 2.0 playground. But it is not available in developer console.

Comment: This endpoint doesn't give the emails, just like `userinfo`. What could I do wrong?

Comment: If the user doesn't have an email address in their profile, it won't be returned. If you are still having problems, asking your own question on StackOverflow might give you more up-to-date result.

Comment: Do you have a link that confirms the de-deprecation of `userinfo`? I can't seem to find anything, and the deprecation docs are still saying the same thing: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/auth-migration

Comment: are you sure `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` was deprecated ? seems to me that it is still working

Comment: the api `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` is still working! are there any docs from google mentioned the deprecation?

Comment: Ok, I've linked to the docs that say that it was deprecated, that it still exists for backwards compatibility, and what you should be using instead regardless (ie - the latest version of it). I hope this clears everything up.

Answer (score 57):

As of 2017: use the `email` scope. See [Authorizing API requests](http://web.archive.org/web/20190301083744/https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth).

> This **email** scope is equivalent to and replaces the
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to see some up to date answers for a change :)

Comment: Q well and where I have to put those "scope call" definition in "javascript firebase auth calling" ?

Answer (score 17):

For signing in with Google using OAuth 2.0, there's no need to make a separate request to get user's email.

When Google calls the callback URL, it provides a `code` in the query string that you could use to exchange for access token and ID token. The ID token is a JWT that contains identity information about the user, which includes the email address.

See more information here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect

Comment: This is incorrect as documented in the [OAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#2.-obtain-an-access-token-from-the-google-authorization-server.) the tokens returned from an OAuth2 flow are completely opaque and do not contain any information about the user.

Comment: Actually it's correct. The idToken is not like an acccess or refresh token and contains embedded information that is easy to extract. The scope does need to include "openid email" in Google's case for the email address to appear in the idToken though.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo

Comment: This is correct answer and explained beautifully here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795599/google-api-idtoken-constant. Just use below code to extract idToken. `php> $idToken = $client->getOAuth2Service()->getIdToken();`

Answer (score 15):

You'll want to add the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` scope or replace `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo` with it. If you're using the HTML example they provide, you can list multiple scopes separated by a space.

```
<span
  class="g-signin"
  data-callback="signInCallback"
  data-clientid="{{ plus_id }}"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login   
  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email">
</span>
```

Answer (score 12):

To retrieve the email address, you need to include the scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" as mentioned in this document. If this scope is included while you generate the refresh token, you should be able to get the email address of the authenticating user by making the following request:

you can call this with your own access token then will give the response

`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token="YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"`

response will look like this

```
{
  "sub": "1057abc98136861333615xz",
  "name": "My Name",
  "given_name": "My",
  "family_name": "Name",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14qiJarwP9rRw7IzxO40anYi4pTTAU_xseuRPFeeYFg",
  "email": "MyName@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "locale": "en"
}
```

or simply you can just write a function

```
import requests
def get_user_email(access_token):
    r = requests.get(
            'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
            params={'access_token': access_token})
    return r.json()
```

Comment: Do we have similar endpoint to get service account?

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking why my server did not get email in response to /oauth2/v2/userinfo api call. It was only once that I saw this & it has been working well in past.

The answer gave good lead. While fixing this, there were several other resources that helped. Still I am not sure whether expecting always email in the response is ok. so - put error handling in code in case emails are not returned.

1. Google api documentation about [migrating to google+ signin](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable).
2. [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#userinfo.email)
3. People resource [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)
4. Add google+ api to the project using [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/). The complimentary (quota) of calls is quite high (20m for google+ signin api per day).
5. Add error handling & logging in server code in case api returns no emails. In my case, I was looking only type='account' email.

Comment: Q well and where I have to put those "scope call" definition in "javascript firebase auth calling" ?

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a bit of a challenge as Google does not provide an email by default. You must specifically request it from Google Plus.

```js
const scope = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me', // request access here
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
];

auth.generateAuthUrl({
  access_type: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent',
  scope: scope,
});

const plus = google.plus({ version: 'v1', auth });
const me = await plus.people.get({ userId: 'me' });
const userEmail = me.data.emails[0].value;
```

There is a full version in this blog post I wrote: https://medium.com/@jackscott/how-to-use-google-auth-api-with-node-js-888304f7e3a0

Comment: It goes without saying that this should be placed in an `async` function or else the last two lines should use a `.then().catch()` pattern. 

Also `const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2("client_id", "client_secret", "redirect_url");` above.

Answer (score 5):

by using [google nodejs sdk](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client):

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      googleClientIdPublic,
      googleClientSecret,
      googleRedirectUriPublic
    );

//scope you need: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

const googleAuth = google.oauth2({
      version: "v2",
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });

const googleUserInfo = await googleAuth.userinfo.get();
const email = googleUserInfo.data.email;
```

[more info](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/oauth2.js)

Answer (score 1):

I have been following Prisoner's answer right above, and it helped me... until I received the email from Google Developers about how Google+ API will be shutdown on March 7, 2019.

I scrounged around and found this solution to get the email using an `id_token` that is returned when you authorize an app with the `email` scope on your developer console.

From [Google Sign-in for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library):

> To validate an ID token in PHP, use the Google API Client Library for
>   PHP. Install the library (for example, using Composer):
>
> `composer require google/apiclient`
>
> Then, call the verifyIdToken() function. For example:
>
> ```
> require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
>
> // Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.
>
> $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
> $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
> if ($payload) {
>   $userid = $payload['sub'];
>   // If request specified a G Suite domain:
>   //$domain = $payload['hd'];
> } else {
>   // Invalid ID token
> }
> ```

This will return an array that contains the user information, that also contains the email of the user who logged in. Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here to the identical issue:
[how to get email after using google OAuth2 in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612997/how-to-get-email-after-using-google-oauth2-in-c)

- In your **scopes** variable. Use the value "email" not the
  full https address. Scope keywords in the web link are separated by spaces. I solve your issue with scopes written as: **profile email openid**.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile

For gmails api, add this to nodejs code:

```
function getUsersEmail (auth) {
  const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth})
  gmail.users.getProfile({
    userId: 'me'
  }, (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err)
    console.log(data.emailAddress)
  })
}
```

Gmails api: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/

Comment: this gives me: The API returned an error: Error: Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

Change the `authorizationRequest` with given scope: `scope=openid%20email%20profile` and use userinfoapi. [This link worked for me](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following minimal code, which include '*/userinfo.email' and '@google-cloud/local-auth' package:

```
const path = require('path');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { authenticate } = require('@google-cloud/local-auth');

const scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
];
async function runSample() {
    const auth = await authenticate({
        keyfilePath: path.join(__dirname, 'oauth2.keys.json'),
        scopes: scope
    });
    google.options({ auth });

    const dat = await google.oauth2('v2').userinfo.get()
    console.log(dat.data.email);
}

if (module === require.main) {
    runSample().catch(console.error);
}
module.exports = runSample;
```