# Google Api IDtoken, Constant?

Tags: php, google-signin

So I'm creating a wordpress site and implementing the Google Sign-in API,

I designed it so EVERY user has the same password(a Long 'gibberish' string).

//PHP CODE BELOW

```
$usrname =$_REQUEST['/:)REQUEST EMAIL FROM GOOGLE API AFTER SIGN IN:(/']; 

$creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $usrname;
    $creds['user_password'] = 'AIzaSyA9s0cRKrGuhN7oLsjQUxlA1oZroWdWXbc';
    $creds['remember'] = true;
```

but then I realised anyone could just impersonate a user by passing their email to the function through JS.

EDIT: plus is saw this.

"Warning: Do not accept plain user IDs, such as those you can get with the GoogleUser.getId() method, on your backend server. A modified client application can send arbitrary user IDs to your server to impersonate users, so you must instead use verifiable ID tokens to securely get the user IDs of signed-in users on the server side."

So I'm thinking of using a CONSTANT string gotten from the google api so that string becomes their password.

I need to know if the googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token; is a constant variable so I could use that as the password.

by "Constant" I mean if the user AUTHEs my application in 2010 and the ID token is "XPOXVSCWSW32526C", if the user needs to sign in again in 2017 the ID token would still be "XPOXVSCWSW32526C".

Thanks.!

Comment: Use the backend part of the approach described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html ... send the ID token (which is not constant) to your server over HTTPS, validate it with a library (e.g. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Client.php#L480 ) on your server, then use and store the user ID (ID token subject) to look up or create your user entry, then issue a session cookie or token. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: $curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$php composer.phar require google/apiclient:dev-master
$php -a
php > require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
php > $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => '<web_client_id>']);
php > print_r($client->verifyIdToken('<id_token_string>'));

Comment: Thanks :) I'd love to mark this as the answer, but its a comment :|

Comment: OK, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using the ID token with the backend architecture described in [this post on the Google developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html):

- Send the ID token string (which is not constant) to your server over HTTPS
- validate it with a library (for example, [an open source one in PHP from Google](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/Client.php#L480)) on your server. Be sure to provide your **web** OAuth client ID (should look like X.apps.googleusercontent.com)

`$curl -sS getcomposer.org/installer | php`

`$php composer.phar require google/apiclient:dev-master`

`$php -a`

`php > require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`

`php > $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => 'web_client_id']);`

`php > print_r($client->verifyIdToken('id_token_string'));`

- successful validation of this token for your client ID is what you should use in place of a password for the given user for secure authentication
- use and store the user ID (ID token 'sub' field) as **a string** to look up or create your user entry, not an email address, which may change
- issue a session cookie or token for the user

See the [developer guide](http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) for more details

Comment: Very beautifully explained. It'd be better to add this as second-last line. `php> $idToken = $client->getOAuth2Service()->getIdToken();`