# Google OAuth2 API v2 userinfo always returns null for email

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm trying to get the authenticated user's email addresses.

I've done the authentication with scopes

```
email
profile
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

This call returns null for email but name, link, picture, etc are populated:

```
Userinfoplus userinfo2 = oauth2.userinfo().v2().me().get().execute();
log.info(userinfo2.toString());
```

outputs:

```
{
  "family_name" : "Homlish",
  "gender" : "male",
  "given_name" : "Paul",
  "id" : "107004799409225320539",
  "link" : "https://plus.google.com/107004799409225320539",
  "locale" : "en",
  "name" : "Paul Homlish",
  "picture" : "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bCRlXUqr__E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABR8/LQCliyz_jgI/photo.jpg"
}
```

inspecting I can see an email field, but it is null.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Although the scopes I am using don't prompt the user for extra permissions, are there any scopes I can delete as not needed?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Can you show us the response given by Google (HTTP Status) ?

Comment: switching to HttpResponse r = oauth2.userinfo().v2().me().get().executeUnparsed(); I see 200, "OK"

Comment: Your response contains "emails" like this ?

`"kind": "plus#person",
 "etag": "\"rthtrsgd\"",
 "gender": "male",
 "emails": [
  {
   "value": "28@gmail.com",
   "type": "account"
  }
 ],
 "objectType": "person",
 "id": "`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",`

Comment: updated question to show the toString output which does not show nulls.  Inspecting in the debugger also shows email is null.

Comment: I think it miss you the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Comment: according to this post, that scope is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442668/google-oauth-api-to-get-users-email-address

Comment: But no choice if you really want emails

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150186/discussion-between-phomlish-and-cylexx).

Comment: turned out my scopes were not being read correctly.  I trimmed it down to JUST email scope and I now receive the primary email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting scope to 'email', authenticating, and using com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential and com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2 I was able to receive email:

```
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(tokenFromAuthentication); 
        Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential)
                .setApplicationName("Oauth2")
                .build();
        Userinfoplus userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
```