# How I can get user info profile from Google API?

Tags: node.js, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I have to implement signIn by google account.

I want to some suggestions.

I created project in google console. Added scope user info.profile

I'm following course instruction on internet, but I still cannot get userinfo ( email, name, age ... ).

Step:

- Get code in url redirect_uri by client_id
- Get token https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token by code, client_id, client_secret ...
- Try call to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken to get info but only object

```
{
    "azp": "155122683461-51hq2n932svo4ajbt98ic0q67m4tuj5o.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "aud": "155122683461-51hq2n932svo4ajbt98ic0q67m4tuj5o.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "sub": "108865940357700877124",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "exp": "1554094721",
    "expires_in": "3326",
    "access_type": "offline"
}
```

Can you guys give me an example :(

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, for example, how about this endpoint? ``GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=accessToken``

Comment: Sorry. From now I know why api get token ( https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token ) always return error : 
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

Comment: @VũAnhDũng invalid_grant is a different question i suggest you open a new question with that and add your code.

Comment: @DaImTo I tried with ```GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=accessToken``` But response not contain email ???

Comment: The response will only contain an email if you request the email scope.  As i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: In config google project (console.develop.google.com) I have added user info.profile to scope.

Comment: ```https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001&client_id=607602703319-5654m0luqaaqjq14vjjei27qo86a9ct0.apps.googleusercontent.com```


I also add to url to get Authentication

Comment: Ok thanks. I resolved the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google OAuth API to get user's email address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442668/google-oauth-api-to-get-users-email-address)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## people api

The infomration you are looking for can be found on [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}
```

tip send Field mask with no space - `person.emailAddresses,person.birthdays` It reads form [person info](https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info) so the user will have had to fill in this information

However you will need to add the scopes to get the information you want

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
```

You can test it here [Google Apis explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.get?resourceName=people%252Fme&requestMask.includeField=person.emailAddresses%252Cperson.birthdays&_h=2&)

A node.js quick start for google people api can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs)

## userinfo endpoint

The userinfo endpoint can also be used but it does not return the information you are looking for

You need to request the **email scope** to have seen email in the below response the user must grant you permission to see their email the following is standard response for profile scope only.

```
GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlveBiwp4-NTPLU9VN3rn1enty11KOdQHGcyfZd1xJ1Ee9eGS2Pw2nJ7KDUBQPa-uT-AoKDQdoVigU6bruVIB1a3fiBu1n
```

response

```
{
  "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-a1CWlFnA5xE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAl1I/UcwPajZOuN4/photo.jpg", 
  "name": "Linda Lawton", 
  "family_name": "Lawton", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+LindaLawton", 
  "given_name": "Linda", 
  "id": "117200475532672775346"
}
```

## scopes

You should consult the node [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/nodejs) for how to work with scopes.  Remember you will need to request access of the user again if you change the scope in your code.

```
const SCOPES = ['profile', 'email'];
```

Comment: I can't see that scope in list scope can choice

Comment: which scope and which list? Scopes are just strings you can add what ever you want.

Comment: ```GET /oauth2/v2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com```
Working but I need user.email in response

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer and in your other comment. You need to add the email scope when authorizing your user if you want return email in userinfo endpoint.

Comment: ```https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.emails.read,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read&response_type=code&access_type=offline&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3001/oauth/google&client_id=607602703319-5654m0luqaaqjq14vjjei27qo86a9ct0.apps.googleusercontent.com```

Comment: Do you mean set scope to url request authorization? I set it as above but gt error: ```400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_scope

Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile,https://ww```

Comment: check the scope section of my answer.   I think that you should open a new question and post your code this is beyond the scope of your current question which was just about which api to use.  if you post a new question with your code i would be able to help you address any issues with your code more efficiently

Comment: Thanks. I tried add scope userinfo.email and it working

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have the userinfo call working fine: `"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` but was just wondering if there are proper GoogleClient libraries (java) somewhere encapsulating this. I don't want to use people API as is not currently enabled for our app and all we want is the email address to display with the token. Thanks

Comment: @Sodved it is not recommend using the userinfo endpoint as its not guaranteed to always return all of the claims, on occasion they will not be returned to you as its not intended to be a profile data resource.   If you want to get user profile data then you should use the people api which will give you access to all the data you need.

Comment: All I want is the email that was used to get the refresh token. But I'll talk with our GCP team about enabling the People API