# How to get the login email after logging with google by PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am able to login with Google by PHP. But could not find how to get the login email after login with which the user logged in. It is very important to get the login email. Please help me out. Thanks in advance. I am getting the code google returns after login and the access token. Here is my code:

```
  $client_id = '870872749542-hf3ll1kbpnucn8rm67p2s83h5j890og5.apps.googleusercontent.com';
  $client_secret = '_Q4sSVLD90RKZ5H1seRPrw6D';
  $redirect_uri = 'http://symmetrix.website/staging/property/gcontacts.php';
  $simple_api_key = 'AIzaSyANQX5L0uNzRb2wYOq3t0VHvVLcfoi71Gs';
  $max_results = 30;
  $auth_code = $_GET["code"];

  $fields = array(
    'code' => urlencode($auth_code),
    'client_id' => urlencode($client_id),
    'client_secret' => urlencode($client_secret),
    'redirect_uri' => urlencode($redirect_uri),
    'grant_type' => urlencode('authorization_code')
  );
  $post = '';
  foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $post .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
  }
  $post = rtrim($post, '&');

  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 5);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  curl_close($curl);

  $response = json_decode($result);
  if (isset($response->access_token)) {
     $accesstoken = $response->access_token;
  }
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442668/google-oauth-api-to-get-users-email-address) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for replying. But will I get the login email with https://openidconnect.googleapis.com/v1/userinfo? I.e. the email with which the user logged in?

Comment: What is mean by "login email" here? Do you mean the "email address" used to logon? Or a "email message" send as a reaction to the logon event?

Comment: Yes yes. The "email address" with which the user logged in. Please it is very important for me to get that.